# How to make "domain.com/search/q=query" from "domain.com/search/query" without breaking $_GET

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite

**Hello!**

I've got:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/search/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ index.php?page=catalog&type=search&category=$1&q=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/search/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=catalog&type=search&category=$1&q=$2&pg=$3 [L]
```

and with that i've get this:

> domain.com/catalog/search/all/QUERY
>
> domain.com/catalog/search/all/QUERY/PAGE

but i need:

> domain.com/catalog/search/all/?=QUERY
>
> domain.com/catalog/search/all/?q=QUERY/PAGE

and with still access to: $_GET['q'] and $_GET['pg']

**Any help appreciated!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `QSA` to the [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)'s list of flags:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/search/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ index.php?page=catalog&type=search&category=$1&q=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^catalog/search/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=catalog&type=search&category=$1&q=$2&pg=$3 [L,QSA]
```